# Game server - How can I block connections from other countries?

Tags: port, blocking, international, traffic-filtering

I have a small server at home that I plan on putting a few game servers on, but I want to make sure only people from my country can join it.

Is it possible to filter connection attempts to my server based on port? Say a game runs on port 12345, could I block all international traffic to that single port?

Comment: What OS are you running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course it is possible, you simple need a database like 
Maxmind  or IPLocation (http://www.ip2location.com), there you will find the information needed.

Regarding the port, you can use any opensource firewall to filter any access to that port coming from outside your country.

Answer (score 1):

even if you got a database of your contries IP comnmon adresses resp. ranges, it would be futile to filter against it because it can be circumvented via VPN and other form of tunneling and proxies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IPv4 is geographically distributed, so unless you have a database of "national" or "international" IPs, it's a no go.

Comment: Actually, it is. IP-Ranges are getting assigned to the ISPs, which are (most of the time) located in one country.